# My JavaScript code crashes in Chrome, when script tries to make fixed element visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have added few elements with "visibility:hidden; position:fixed;" to the top of the page and for some reason, when I launch the script in Chrome, it makes "#pageOverlay" visible, but fails to unhide other elements. Here is the JS function that fails:

```
function showImage(element) {
//locating currentGalleryItemIndex

for (currentGalleryItemIndex = firstGalleryItemIndex; currentGalleryItemIndex <= lastGalleryItemIndex; currentGalleryItemIndex++) {
    if (galleryItems[currentGalleryItemIndex] === element) break;
}

//general settings

fillPreviewArea();

pageOverlay.style.visibility = "visible";

previewArea.style.visibility = "visible";

previewAreaCloseLink.style.visibility = "visible";

previewAreaActive = true;
}
```

The same thing doesn't happen in Firefox and IE11 and it only works in chrome if I change all "position:fixed;" to "position:absolute;"; which isn't what I want to use.

The page that uses the script is here:

http://spongebobia.com/spongebob-captures/gallery.php

And the actual script is here:

http://spongebobia.com/spongebob-captures/scripts/previewArea.js

How to make it work while keeping "position: fixed;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about ["z-index"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). Your pageOverlay's CSS should look like this:

```
#pageOverlay {
    background: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

and your previewAreaContainer like this:

```
#previewAreaContainer {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -344px;
    width: 670px;
    height: 540px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I had to reconfigure z-indexes to make it work.